# How to approach a d3js tree design

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm new to d3js and javascript in general. I am trying to create an interactive IP administration overview based on modeling json data with d3js. I have got a general idea of what I want to do and I think the right tool for the job is to use d3.layout.tree, which gives me the depth and links between all nodes. However considering this is my first d3js project I can't entirely grasp how to approach this design. I have watched several tutorials, studied examples based on d3.layout.tree, such as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025. But the curve is to steep to see the path to the solution.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish roughly based on this json data: http://pastebin.com/dajCKb2P

```
Initially rendered as:

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.10.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------

On-click 10.20.0.0/16 (type supernet):

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.200.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------

On-click 10.0.0.0/16: (collapse all other parents)

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.1.0/24                                 |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.100.0/24                               |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.200.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------

On-click 10.0.1.0/24 (type supernet):

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.1.0/24                                 |
    -----------------------------------------------
     |  -------------------------------------------
     -- | 10.0.1.64/26                            |
     |  -------------------------------------------
     |  -------------------------------------------
     -- | 10.0.1.128/26                           |
        -------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------
    | 10.0.100.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------
    | 10.0.200.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------

On-click 10.0.100.64/26 (type subnet):

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.1.0/24                                 |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   -- | 10.0.1.64/26                            |
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   |/                                           |
 |   /                                            |   
 |  /                                             |    
 | /                                              |
 |/                                               |
 /                                                |
---------------------------------------------------
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |   <-- rendered based on hosts array in subnet nodes
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
---------------------------------------------------
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   -- | 10.0.1.128/26                           |
 |      -------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.100.0/24                               |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.200.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------

On-click 10.0.1.128/26 (type subnet):
(auto collapse all children under other nodes on same level)

---------------------------------------------------
| 10.0.0.0/16                                     |
---------------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.1.0/24                                 |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   -- | 10.0.1.64/26                            |
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   |  -------------------------------------------
 |   -- | 10.0.1.128/26                           |
 |      -------------------------------------------
 |    /                                           |
 |   /                                            |   
 |  /                                             |    
 | /                                              |
 |/                                               |
 /                                                |
---------------------------------------------------
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |   <-- rendered based on hosts array in subnet nodes
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x |
---------------------------------------------------       
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.100.0/24                               |
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 |  -----------------------------------------------
 -- | 10.0.200.0/24                               |
    -----------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16                                    |
---------------------------------------------------

Super and subnet "bars" to be rendered with indication of % of usage based on children or hosts:
(++++ is different gradient color)
---------------------------------------------------
| 10.20.0.0/16+++++++++++60%|                     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

(I will output the json file myself from another system, so it is tweak-able)

I have got a rough outline set up to access the json code and to calculate the tree:

```
var x_margin = 20,
    y_margin = 20,
    height = window.innerHeight - y_margin,
    width = window.innerWidth - x_margin;

var body = d3.select("body");
var svg = body.append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

function supernet_usage(supernet) {
    //returns the amount of space used based on children in given supernet in percentage
}

function subnet_usage(subnet) {
    //returns the amount of space used based on hosts in given subnet in percentage
}

function supernet(supernet) {
    //renders a supernet view of the given subnet
}

function subnet(subnet) {
    //renders a subnet view of the given subnet
}

function calc_hosts(length) {
    //Calculates the number of hosts in an IP subnet based on masklength
    return Math.pow(2,(32 - length))
}

function max_subnet_size (data) {
    // returns largest subnet size in this level of the hierarchie
    return d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.net_masklength;} );
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

function main() {
    // Main application code
    d3.json("/d3/data.json", function(data) {
        // Executing all actions is done inside the json function call, because of asynchronous handling otherwise
        //console.log(data);
        root = data[0]

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

        console.log(nodes);
        console.log(links);

    });
}

main();
```

Could someone roughly outline the steps I would need to take to get there?
Something like this wuld really be helpful:
- have a function that does these things:
- Call this function in a foreach loop
- enter the objects with required attributes
- etc

Comment: It's not clear at all to me why you want to use D3.js for this design. It could be much simpler to implement with plain old JavaScript and some basic HTML and CSS. Why don't you try it that way first to avoid complicating things with D3? Then, once you have the code and interactions working, it will be much easier to add in D3.js as an enhancement if desired (though I don't think you need it).

Comment: If you don't want to code it yourself, there are tons of JavaScript accordion libraries available. [Here's one](http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/) from 2007 that still works fine. (Look at the vertical nested example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data can be simply added to a d3.js tree diagram.

Roughly (depending on how you're going to display it);

- You load your data
- Declare the layout (size and so on) of your
  diagram
- Append the overall SVG element to your page
- Declare the
  'root' point of your tree
- Apply your data to the d3.layout.tree
  process

...that could go a little like;

- Assign the nodes and links using d3.js magic.
- Adjust the depth of each branching of the tree
- Append the nodes (circles in this case)
- Append the links

An example using your data is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/db249428022f0a761f6d);

So it looks a bit like this;

[image]

(I did have to remove a stray comma that was rendering the data 'troublesome')

You can also make it interactive (click on the nodes to collapse and grow) like the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/181f76d7757214982fb7) (again with your data);

[image]

You can style the links or nodes dependent on your data or show more information at the nodes to your hearts delight.

This is based on the code and instructions [here](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-tree-diagrams).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that elaborate answer d3noob. As you can see in my initial post, I already headed in the direction of using the tree functionality. Thanks for putting it in into my context, this should provide a great framework for me to work around. How would you do the distinction between the supernet and subnet nodes? A subnet node also contains an array of hosts, which I want to render in a different way.
Also, how do I make sure both 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.20.0.0/16 are picked up? It seems 10.0.0.0/16 has been used as the root node and therefore 10.20/16 wasn't picked up. Thanks.

Comment: To render the hosts in a subnet diffently you just check the "type" while rendering the node and colour or size appropriately (there are examples of that in the book.  To use both 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.20.0.0/16 you would need a single node which they would both be children of. Not quite sure how you would represent that.